# relational model from erd

Tags: model, erd, relational

I currently developing an relational model from two separate ERDs. I would simply like to know if anyone can notice any mistakes in my relational model. I will upload both ERDs followed by the listed values in the following form -
**Table name ( Attributes, Primary Key,Foreign key)**

[CLICK HERE TO VIEW THE ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nn3b0.png)

```
ENROLLS(STUDENTID (PK),SECNUM(PK))
STUDENT (STUDENTID(PK),FNAME,LNAME,EMAIL)
COURSESECTION(TIME,CLASSROOM,COURSECODE(PK),SECNUM(PK))
DEPARTMENT(DEPTNAME(PK),PHONE,ADDRESS,COURSECODE(PK))
COURSE(COURSECODE(PK),NAME,SECNUM(FK))
SEMESTER(SEASON(PK),YEAR,STARTDATE,ENDDATE)
ISOFFEREDIN(SEASON(PK),COURSECODE(PK))
```

Comment: The relational model i currently have.

Comment: This smells of a homework question.  You won't find much help here in the way this question is worded. Perhaps edit your question to let us know exactly what you might be unsure of.

Comment: You've got child keys in parent tables - SECNUM in COURSE and COURSECODE in DEPARTMENT. If the association is determined by the parent, you can only associate one child per parent. Do it the other way around, put parent keys in child tables - the child must determine the association. The rest looks good.

Comment: Thanks alot sir reaanb and dangel.

Comment: Your textbook will say how to map ERDs to databases. Read it. Right now you misunderstand. Every box & diamond gets a table. FKs to (regular or associative) entities go in the relationship that associates the entities. Also, give a reference to the particular form of ERD you are using, because they differ. A 1:m relationship can instead be represented without its own table by putting the columns of the table on the 1 side into the table on the M side but this is a good idea only in certain circumstances & depends on the conventions you are taught.